# scala getter method inside println

Tags: scala, setter, getter

I have defined the following class Duck in scala.

```
class Duck{
var size = 1
}

object DuckDemo extends App {
  var f = new Duck
  f.size = 100 
  println(f.size = 600)
  println(f.size)
}
```

It is giving me the output as

```
()
600
```

I failed to understand the result of `println(f.size = 100)`. How is it reaching to "`()`"? I know, it acts like a getter but wants to understand the reason behind the result.

Thanks.

Comment: I am quite surprised there are no warnings for this. Or are they?

Comment: @Suma : There were no warnings .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation, that you refer to

```
f.size = 100
```

Is actually assignment operation, result of which is `Unit`
If you wanted to make a comparison add another equal sign

```
f.size == 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first println() contains an assignment. Scala won't print this as output.